# Convert string into a list

Tags: string, list, type-conversion

I am getting the below lines as a String:

```
[{"attribute_group":"abc","attribute_name":"bcd","attribute_value":"OTN_NETWORK"},{"attribute_group":"xyz","attribute_name":"yza","attribute_value":"zab"}]
```

How can I convert it to a list such that it's a list of two dictionaries? I'd like to loop over them using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's a JSON string, so you would need to use a JSON parser to serialize it into objects. The exact syntax will change depending on the language you're using.

For example, in JavaScript:

```
const array = JSON.parse('[{"attribute_group":"abc","attribute_name":"bcd","attribute_value":"OTN_NETWORK"},{"attribute_group":"xyz","attribute_name":"yza","attribute_value":"zab"}]')

for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    console.log("ATTRIBUTE VALUE IS " + array[i].attribute_value);
}
```

would print:

```
ATTRIBUTE VALUE IS OTN_NETWORK
ATTRIBUTE VALUE IS fab
```